# log4net not logging after release as ClickOnce winforms application

Tags: c#, log4net, clickonce

I have built an application with two projects - one Windows Forms project and one class library containing my custom controls. I have added log4net to the class library with this configuration in log4net.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="unicodeFFFE" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

The file has Build Action set to Content and Copy to output directory set as Copy always. In the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I use the logger from the control like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using log4net;

namespace ControlProject
{
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly ILog log;

        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }

        private void logButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.Info("Log something");
        }
    }
}
```

Now all this is nice and works fine when using Visual Studio (this configuration works in both Debug and Release mode). But once I publish the Windows Forms project, the logging doesn't happen anymore. When I attach to the app from the Visual Studio, I can see the log isn't configured properly - there are no appenders. I ran out of ideas what to do with this. I tried meddling with configs (both App.config, log4net.config), tried adding this line:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

I have also tried to add this decorator to make sure the log initialization method isn't optimized out:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

Could someone please advise how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to care for couple of things when you deploy winform application via ClickOnce.

1. Where to keep log4net.config file

   In click once, this file is inaccessible. You may want to think to put this file in common folder (MyDocuments / AppData etc) and reconfigure log4net at application startup programmatically.
2. Where to write log files

   Same goes to log files as well. Log files are inaccessible, ClickOnce application goes to new folder for each version. You need to file a common location to write the log files to (like MyDocuments / AppData folders). At the application startup you need to load all the appenders and reconfigure them point to new log location.

The link below may help you

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/139eb00c-c39b-47ff-9401-b67e92589d81/logging-in-clickonce-looking-for-a-general-advice?forum=winformssetup